# DataRow Column Has Value When Read One Way, But Not When Read a Different Way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read values from a DataSet in C#/ASP.NET returned from a stored procedure. Normally, the DefaultView from that DataSet is passed into a GridView in an ASP.NET page. in that event, a particular column I'm interested in has a value. However, if I try to read a DataRow and get the column value, it comes through as empty.

For example, this will display a value:

```
DataSet ds = //////
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
grdQuotes.DataSource = dv;
grdQuotes.DataBind();
```

This, however, gives me no value:

```
DataSet ds = //////
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
    String value1 = (String)row["DOReviewDate"];
    String value2 = ((Object)row["DOReviewDate"]).ToString();
    String value3 = row.Field<String >("DOReviewDate");
}
```

All three variables end up empty.

I'm pretty lost on where to go with this, as it's apparent that there's a value being pulled from the SQL database, otherwise it wouldn't display in the GridView table on the page. Also, I can get the rest of the column values in the row without problem. Interestingly enough, there is one other column exhibiting the same behavior.

**-- EDIT --**

Attempt to iterate through rows and columns to get data:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        r.Append(String.Format("{0} | ", row[c]));
    }
    r.Append("END");
    sb.AppendLine(r.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column DOReviewDate?

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, I suggest you write a bit of code to iterate through all the `Tables`, `Rows`, and Fields, so you can see what is going on (or you can set a breakpoint and inspect via Watch).  Might be that Table[0] contains a message from T-SQL (e.g. if you forgot to `SET NOCOUNT ON`)

Comment: The data type is **String**.

Also, I have iterated through the full list of columns, and having it kick out data referencing with a DataColumn instead still yields nothing. As for what's getting returned from the database, I have no real control over that as I didn't create it, nor do I manage it. I'll add an edit to my post to show what I attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to locate the stored procedure powering this functionality. It's returning empty values for the columns I need. There's nothing but an empty string designating what to return. So, while I can't seem to find the functionality within the page construction, it looks like there is some sort of join or alternate search pulling the data, and I believe I found the table to pull from. Guess I'll just have to take this initial data returned to me and use it to pull from the other table. Or, I guess, maybe make my own SQL search with a join. Either way, the stored procedure does not itself contain a join to the table I need. This is what was in the stored procedure:

```
'' as DOReviewDate
```